# How to log ship from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014

Tags: sql-server, log-shipping

I need to log ship from SQL Server 2008 to SQL Server 2014 but server is not allowing me do it in stand by mode.

I have done googling also but still did not get correct answer please explain if this is possible and how or not ?

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Answer (score 1):

No it is not possible, actually upgrade is required to restore the lower version backup file on the higher version server so you can only use logshiping with restoring mode only.